# $\operatorname{rank}(M)=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B-A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Let $A, B \in M_n,$  and
$M=
\begin{pmatrix}
A & A \\
 A& B
\end{pmatrix}\\$

I have to prove that $$
\operatorname{rank}(M)=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B-A)$$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\pmatrix{I&0\\-I & I}\pmatrix{A&A\\A&B} = \pmatrix{A & A\\0 & B-A}, \\
\pmatrix{A & A\\0 & B-A} \pmatrix{I & -I\\0 & I} = \pmatrix{A & 0\\0&B-A}.
$$

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}I & 0 \\ -I& I\end{pmatrix} $ is invertible so $\operatorname{rank}(M)=\operatorname{rank}\begin{pmatrix}A& A\\ 0& B-A\end{pmatrix} $ but why is $\operatorname{rank}\begin{pmatrix}A& A\\ 0& B-A\end{pmatrix}=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B-A)$?

Comment: @Alex see my latest edit

Comment: @W Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$